# Reuse PHP script with htaccess redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have written a php script which lists all files and directories from the current directory where the php file is located. I want to use this script for many different directories and it would be great if I can reuse it for all of them. Is this possible without to put a new php file in all these folders? I think of something like htaccess redirect so if the user visits an URL to a specific folder the script is executed with the folder as parameter but it does not lie in the directory itself.

I hope you understand what I want and have any ideas for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you need to make an .htaccess file.
So basically your code will reside in index.php which is in the root folder. 
Now use the below code in .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^?]*)$ /index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

now when the user tries to access sub folders, the folder path will come as a parameter named "path" to index.php

Comment: Thank you for this. But it only works fairly good: Let's say I want to list all files and folders from the directory Test. Then I have to call domain.com/Test/bla.html - if I call domain/Test it does not work. Can I also handle this with htaccess?